# Impossible? Or not?

Tags: visible-light, speed-of-light, speed

If the universe is expanding at light speed, and you stand on the edge moving out, if you look across the universe, then you will see twice the light speed, why is that?

Comment: What would be twice the speed of light?

Comment: What do you mean by "_and you stand on the edge moving out_"?

Comment: Are you thinking of eg being on the edge of balloon that is expanding? If the radius expands atat speed c, does the diameter expand as 2c?

Comment: Is that your question?

Comment: innifree is correct